# Ubuntu transmits TTL 0 multicast packets

Tags: networking

IP packets with TTL 0 shall not leave host.

But when I start application which multicasts UDP packets with TTL 0, I see packets with TTL 0 leaving host for few seconds, and coming to normal behavior of TTL 0. This most likely happens after reboot and first start of application.

I confirmed packets with TTL 0 leaving host with tcpdump:

```
05:31:39.048304 IP (tos 0x0, id 14487, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    192.168.1.200.46968 > 239.0.0.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
05:31:39.049594 IP (tos 0x0, id 14488, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    192.168.1.200.46968 > 239.0.0.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
05:31:39.051601 IP (tos 0x0, id 14489, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    192.168.1.200.46968 > 239.0.0.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
05:31:39.053584 IP (tos 0x0, id 14490, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    192.168.1.200.46968 > 239.0.0.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
```

As we can see ttl is not displayed which means TTL 0, as confirmed from tcpdump man page: https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html (search `ttl`, it clearly indicated: `ttl is the time-to-live; it is not reported if it is zero`).

There are no any `iptables` rules running.

`uname -a`: `Linux mydevice 4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 10:07:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

What can be the cause for this behavior, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: may be stackoverflow is better place for this question, as it is more of programming related. Someone can move

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to join multicast group with

`setsockopt(sockFd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&mcastJoinReq), sizeof(ip_mreq))`

before multicasting with `sendto()`.

My assumption always has been that I don't need to join multicast when I have to only send multicast, i.e. I won't ever call `recvfrom()` to receive multicast. But regardless of only sending / only receiving, we have to join multicast.

Comment: Hi @nullptr, could you tell me where you got this insight from? We could not find it in the linux networking documentation. Thanks!

Comment: I traced syscalls in other programs which were working fine, and found out that I have to join multicast. I dont know any documentation, but this is my observation and it works.

Comment: Thanks @nullptr, do you still know which programs that where so we could ask their developers about it?